# Refresh page data upon change to database data on all clients

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm developing a very generic website, SPA to be specific for an event. The page consists of information about the event, and also activities happening during the event ( retrieved from database). The event/activity details can be edited through forms available on the web app. Besides that, there is also one 'chat box' which is created through simple post and get to a database (php).

But the thing is, the data on the page is not updated until the page is refreshed.

I would like the data to be to refreshed (without refreshing the page), and applies to all clients on the webpage.

Example 1: If I were to add an activity, it should list out at the page without needing the page to be refreshed on all clients on the webpage.

Example 2: If I were to post a message on the chatbox, the message should appear without the page being refreshed, and the message should appear on all devices which are on the page.

Currently, I am using some html,css, AngularJS, Bootstraps and some simple php.

What topic should I look on / explore to implement this feature?

To be exact : I want something which refreshes data on all client whenever a http.post /put/delete is called

Comment: You will want to check out web sockets. One for PHP would be Ratchet. Here is a tutorial on that: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-quickly-build-a-chat-app-with-ratchet/

Comment: Use websockets OR a requests loop. Web sockets will connect to the server, and there is an event system where the server can send an event to the browser and vice versa. The simpler option, if no need for "real time", is simply use angular's $timeout service to get the fresh data in the background every X milliseconds, for example, every 1 second for the chat to keep is "active", and every 5 seconds for the activities (the numbers are just an example of what I think would be reasonable)